# Setting up WFFM for "Sitecore® Web Experience Manager 8.2" on Azure

Tags: wffm, azure

how to setup Web form for marketers on azure. i have created app services using "Sitecore® Web Experience Manager 8.2" on azure.

Comment: did you check this ? https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/39/t/4375

Comment: if you try to install WFFM on Azure Paas it will not work. WFFM is not compatibile with  Sitecore on Azure App Serverce. https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/201557

Answer (score 2):

At this time, you cannot. WFFM is not currently compatible with Sitecore PaaS on Azure.

[image]

Reference: [Sitecore XP on Microsoft Azure Compatibility Table](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/201557)